# botframework directline v3.0 Http 502 and Http503

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

BotBuilder using dialogs : C# 
Botframework-WebChat-master : [0.13.1] - 2018-05-01

When i use directline v3.0 off bot-framework i have alternately Http-502 and Http-503 error (date 14 June 2018). But yesterday those error not appear, i haven't change my server bot code.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been [mitigated](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/history/) (Filter under Azure Bot Service for product and it'll be the most recent post, at 6/14). If you are still running into this issue, please create a [new issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/new) in GitHub.

Comment: I thx for your comment. Today the bot work fine before 9h30 am but now it's the same i din't know if the issues was closed. .

Answer (score 3):

The service is down. 
See the related issue on github.
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4738